# How to extract data from this Promise.all()? Getting TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Tags: node.js

I have two functions I want to run using a Promise.all()

```
var query1 = s3.headObject(getMetaData);
var query2 = s3.listObjects(searchBucket);
```

```
Promise.all([query1, query2]).then(data => {
   console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
}).catch(err => {
   if (err) throw err;
});
```

How ever when I try to read the data I'm getting a `TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON`.

When I use simple callback methods like below: It works

```
s3.headObject(getMetaData, function(err, data){
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("MetaData: " + JSON.stringify(data);
});

s3.listObjects(searchBucket, function(err, data) {
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log("Bucket: " + JSON.stringify(data));
});
```

The responding JSON for each of the two callback methods both have the same format:

```
{
    "AcceptRanges": "bytes",
    "LastModified": "2020-01-19T13:28:55.000Z",
    "ContentLength": 97032,
    "ETag": "\"4236c584667a87cc28a9a6c62ddd3d9a\"",
    "ContentType": "image/jpeg",
    "Metadata": {
        "expected_num_images": "3",
        "event_id": "5"
    }
}
```

How can I read the data from Promise.all() using the two functions above?

Comment: We should clarify before asking someone to help: how do you get `query1`, `query2`?

Comment: typo my bad, s3.headObject is query1, s3.listObjects is query2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need to do `.promise()` at the end. something like this

```
var query1 = s3.headObject(getMetaData).promise();
var query2 = s3.listObjects(searchBucket).promise();

Promise.all([query1, query2]).then(data => {
   console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
}).catch(err => {
   if (err) throw err;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Does it work if you convert the `AWS.Request` to `promise`?

```
// query1, query2 are AWS.Request
var query1 = s3.headObject(getMetaData);
var query2 = s3.listObjects(searchBucket);

// convert query1, query2 to promises:
// Reference https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Request.html
Promise.all([query1.promise(), query2.promise()]).then(data => {
   console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
}).catch(err => {
   if (err) throw err;
});
```

Comment: Yeah I had forgotten the ```.promise``` haha

Comment: Yes, I remember that after more than three times are forgotten. It's not natural to get promises in this way.